# Composition of transformations of a plane

Tags: geometry, linear-transformations

How do I find a composition of linear transformations $$T_a\circ R_A^α\circ T_b$$?

Comment: Simply multiply the matrices together.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel I don't get how a matrix of rotation through an angle around the point A should look like, because of the point A thing.

Comment: Transform so that $A$ is the origin, rotate, transform back.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel found a matrix for the whole rotation. Should have researched more thoroughly. Thank you anyway!

Comment: I wonder if it's possible without matrices: I can't determine the type of the composition transform from the resulting matrix.

Comment: In general, compositions of special matrices will not result in any special kind of matrix.

Comment: Well, I still need to somehow determine what type of transformation it is.

Comment: You can't; there's no special type.

Comment: @Meh Mech what tools are you allowed to use? With complex numbers it is easy (if you are familiar with). This is a translated rotation).

Comment: @user376343 the way I got it, each of the transformations should somehow be represented as a composition of glide reflections across some arbitrary lines (two in this case, because there is only one rotation and hence one angle $$α$$ to be formed)